# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging

Tags: android, firebase, android-multidex

After reading multiple articles, I still can not work out specifically what is happening for me to get this error on build.

> "Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;, sources=[Unknown
>   source file], original message=UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: "

My build.gradle reads as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        applicationId "uk.co.quickdoc.mobileleaks"  // this is the id that your app has

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/classes.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'


    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'


}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: it seems that the classes.jar you are using already contains `firebase-messaging` library

Comment: Hey, thank you!  I commented classes.jar and it worked.  ...  How did you know that this was the issue?